# Get the sub url load it into a new url

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting

Let's say someone comes to my site with this url:

> mywebsite.com/somethingsomething123

I want to create a new url and turn it into this:

> anotherwebsite.com/somethingsomething123

How would I be able to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `location.pathname` ; e.g.,  `var path = location.pathname; var newurl = "anotherwebsite.com"  + path;`

Answer (score 0):

So, Using Javascript you it like this :

```js
var path_Name; // it will be like somethingsomething123
redirect_Url="www.example.com"; // anotherdomain.com
 function test(){ 
 path_Name = window.location.pathname;
window.location.href='http://'+redirect_Url+path_Name
};
```

```html
<button onClick="test()" >Click Here </button>
<h3>I have used test() function on click event you can use it on window.onLoad or any other javascript event </h3>
```

> Note: If you want to do it using url rewriting then specify whether
>   its windows or linux hosting

Comment: well honestly my url looks like
mywebsite.com/qwerty=ok&hello=somethingsomething123    and so does the other site

Comment: and im not looking for a redirrect