# how to Make my website accept tracking

Tags: javascript, html, url, web

How do I make my website accept stuff after the url

mywebsite.com/trafficsource=revcontent&medium=desktop

when ever something like that is done it returns a 404 error
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) portion of a URL, which is traditionally used to pass that sort of data to the server, begins with a question mark character (`?`).

Comment: In reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33188323/get-the-sub-url-load-it-into-a-new-url it does not seem to pick it up

Comment: The query string isn't part of the path (which is why using one doesn't change the path and give you a 404). It's the query string and available via `location.search`.

Comment: also when i implement their code i keep getting mysite.com/test() anyway to explain that?

Comment: You probably wrote `href="test()"` instead of JavaScript.